# Bison parser executing yyparse() twice after error

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a flex scanner and bison parser to be used in a prompt loop and be line based. So far, i've got the following (minified to show my problem):

parser.l

```
/* simple shell lexer, v1 */
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "parser_bison.h"
%}


%%
\"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)+\"                 { return STRING_LITERAL; }
[^ \t\r\n\v\f;=\(\)\|\&>]+          { return WORD; }
=                                   { return ASSIGNMENT; }
"("                                 { return PARENS_OPEN; }
")"                                 { return PARENS_CLOSE; }
;                                   { return CMD_SEP_COL; }
\|\|                                { return CMD_SEP_OR; }
&&                                  { return CMD_SEP_AND; }
">"                                 { return GT; }
[ \t]+                              /* ignore whitespace */;
\n                                  { yyterminate(); }
%%
```

parser.y

```
/* simple shell parser, v1 */
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    void yyerror(char *err);
    int yylex(void);
%}

/* Token declaration */
%token STRING_LITERAL
%token WORD
%token ASSIGNMENT
%token PARENS_OPEN
%token PARENS_CLOSE
%token CMD_SEP_COL
%token CMD_SEP_OR
%token CMD_SEP_AND
%token GT


/* Grammar rules */
%%

cmdlist:
| cmdexpr    { printf("a cmdexpr\n"); }


/* v1: make cmdexpr terminal (ex WORD) and test parens / op assoc */
cmdexpr: WORD
%%


int
parse_commands(void) {
    return yyparse();
}

void
yyerror(char *err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", err);
}
```

As i told this is minified, and parser action simply prints "a cmdexpr" when that's matched. Now, i'm calling this in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


/* Basic cmd and parsing functions */
void prompt_loop(void);
extern void parse_commands(void); /* at parser.ly */


int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 0) {
        while(1) {
            prompt_loop();
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void
prompt_loop(void)
{
    /* print prompt */
    printf("> ");
    parse_commands();
}
```

I've looked at bison and flex docs but i don't quite get it. My problem when i execute the above code is shown by the following output:

```
> asdf
a cmdexpr
> asdf asdf
a cmdexpr
Error: syntax error
> >
```

So the problem is: It kind of works ok when successfully parsed a cmdexpr. When a syntax error happens like in the second example (no rule for two WORDs in a row), the prompt is then printed twice (prompt_loop called twice, in the first one parse_commands just exits inmediatly).

Why is this? What's the way to make this work (meaning not calling parse_commmands/yyparse twice after error)?

**EDIT1**: parser_bison.h at the lexer code above is the header file produced by bison.